Google Maps Geocode API dropping street address portion
I have a application that calls the API, my customer complained that some of the addresses did not have the 'address' portion.
I have confirmed this with postman.
If I submit this to their api (key removed of course)
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=172 PLAZA DR , MORENCI AZ, 85540&key=******************
it returns the formatted address as:
"formatted_address": "Morenci, AZ 85540, USA"
Nothing I have been able to try has changed this, including adding in the name of the business located at that address.
I verified that this is the correct address and it finds it with no problem on google maps, bing, regular google search etc.
this is the full json returned:
{
    "results": [
        {
            "address_components": [
                {
                    "long_name": "Morenci",
                    "short_name": "Morenci",
                    "types": [
                        "locality",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Greenlee County",
                    "short_name": "Greenlee County",
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_2",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Arizona",
                    "short_name": "AZ",
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_1",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "United States",
                    "short_name": "US",
                    "types": [
                        "country",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "85540",
                    "short_name": "85540",
                    "types": [
                        "postal_code"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "formatted_address": "Morenci, AZ 85540, USA",
            "geometry": {
                "bounds": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 33.0690541,
                        "lng": -109.3227911
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 33.0351059,
                        "lng": -109.3412811
                    }
                },
                "location": {
                    "lat": 33.0508859,
                    "lng": -109.3280282
                },
                "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 33.0690541,
                        "lng": -109.3227911
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 33.0351059,
                        "lng": -109.3412811
                    }
                }
            },
            "navigation_points": [
                {
                    "location": {
                        "latitude": 33.0508852,
                        "longitude": -109.3280104
                    }
                }
            ],
            "partial_match": true,
            "place_id": "ChIJEVrvAJHwJ4cRbR95in_T_pc",
            "types": [
                "locality",
                "political"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}


Looks like the geocoder API doesn't know about that address (a data problem), you can suggest that location to Google.  However the places API does (the Places Autocomplete sample finds it).  Is there a reason you are using the geocoder and not the places API?
